# Lebesgue integral calculation LDCT

Tags: real-analysis

Find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0, \frac{n+1}{n}]} \frac{x \cos(ne^x)}{3n^{\sqrt{2}} + \sin{(e^x + 7n^2)}} dx$$

I know that we need to bring out the $n$ from the integral by using a characteristic function $\chi_{[0, \frac{n+1}{n}]}$. I'm thinking of using LDCT, but I can't find a Lebesgue integrable $g$ that can bound $f_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The integrand in absolute value is bounded above by

$$\frac{2\cdot 1}{3 n^{\sqrt 2}-1}\chi_{[0,2]}(x)\le \frac{2\cdot 1}{3 -1}\chi_{[0,2]}(x)=\chi_{[0,2]}(x).$$